# Fast regex to extract strings before and after a time

Tags: java, performance, datetime, regex, comparative-review

I want to get `text1` and `text2` by splitting time format

> ```
> Text1 10:24:02 Text2
> ```

Of the two working regexes below, which is faster?

#### Regex 1

```java
String regex1= "([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})";
```

#### Regex 2

```java
String regex2= "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]";
```

This is the code I've used:

```java
String s="Text1 10:24:02 Text2";
String[] split= s.split(regex1);//regex 1 and 2
System.out.println(split[0]);
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regex 2 is faster, but probably not for the reason that you expect.

You can easily answer questions like these by writing a benchmark.  Here is an example:

```
public static long splitTime(String regex, String text) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        String[] split = text.split(regex);
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return end - start;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex1 = "([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})";
    String regex2 = "[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]";
    String s="Text1 10:24:02 Text2";

    // Warm up the loops
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        splitTime(regex1, s);
        splitTime(regex2, s);
    }

    long time0 = 0, time1 = 0, time2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        time1 += splitTime(regex1, s);
        time2 += splitTime(regex2, s);
        time2 += splitTime(regex2, s);
        time1 += splitTime(regex1, s);
    }

    System.out.println("Regex 1: " + time1);
    System.out.println("Regex 2: " + time2);
}
```

The JIT compiler tends to do funny tricks.  For fairness, I've warmed up the loop by executing both of them without timing.  I've also interleaved the calls to `splitTime` in case the order somehow makes a difference.

I found that Regex 1 is slower than Regex 2 by about 5%.

However, Regex 1 has some capturing parentheses.  If you remove them,

```
    String regex0 = "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";
```

then you get a result that is 16% faster than Regex 2.

Comment: To make it even faster: `[0-9]{2}(?::[0-9]{2}){2}`